# Error debido a la longitud máxima de la variable email

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Veran, tengo una tabla User, la cual tiene la siguiente migración:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table){
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

La cuestión es que quiero ejecutar la migración de la tabla (php artisan migrate:fresh), pero algo me esta fallando.
Concretamente, me encuentro con el siguiente mensaje de error:

***SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes (SQ
  L: alter table `users` add unique `users_email_unique`(`email`))***

Alcanzo a entender que el máximo de longitud que permito es excesivo para el sistema, pero no se donde tendria que corregirlo.
¿Alguien me lo puede aclarar, por favor?

Comment: ¿qué motor de base de datos es?

Comment: @Shaz Utilizo phpMyAdmin, aunque es una versión antigua (no se como actualizarla). Mi versión de Laravel es 5.5

Comment: PhpMyAdmin no es una base de datos, no es más que una herramienta de administración.

Comment: @Shaz ¿Y que seria la BBDD, MySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tal y como dice la documentación de las migraciones, es un problema típico en versiones antiguas de MySQL o MariaDB.

Para resolverlo hay que agregar lo siguiente en el AppServiceProvider:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

Comment: Ha funcionado. Es una buena molestia lo de tener una versión antigua.

Comment: Es más, he actualizado a una versión más reciente de phpMyAdmin y sigo teniendo que incluir este código cada vez que creo un nuevo programa. ¿Como evito necesitar volver a hacerlo?